# Use Underscore.js in a Titanium Alloy project

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

How do I use the built in underscore library in a Titanium Alloy project.

In the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Controllers-section-src-34636384_safe-id-QWxsb3lDb250cm9sbGVycy1FeHRlbmRpbmdBbGxveSxVbmRlcnNjb3JlLmpzYW5kQmFja2JvbmUuanM) it says to do the following:

```
var _ = require("alloy/underscore")._;
```

However, whenever I do this, I get the following error:

```
17:22:55 [ERROR] [iphone, 10.3.3, 192.168.0.64] {
"message": "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_.extend')", 
"line": 1179, 
"column": 6, 
"stack": "Controller
createController
onClickDetails
"}
```

So my question is, how can I use the built in Underscore.js library in Alloy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out underscore is already imported, so you can just use it without actually doing a require statement. e.g.

```
Ti.API.info(_.VERSION);
```